# How to render PHP pages in Tomcat

Tags: php, apache, tomcat

I have deployed a .war web app to Tomcat, but when I try accessing the project like: localhost:8080/example/test.php instead of it rendering the web page, it displays the page's code instead. How can I make it so that the page is rendered?

Comment: @machavity that question uses an outdated PHP version

Comment: The installation will be the same